# I am having problem installing anything on ubuntu: Errors were encountered while processing: kexi

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, 18.04

I am not able to install anything on Ubuntu 18.04. I always get this error message `Errors were encountered while processing:kexi`.
I have tried,

```
sudo apt install kexi
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   
sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

Here is the complete error output

```
dpkg: error processing package kexi (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kexi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading the error message, it basically tells you what you need to do:

```
dpkg: error processing package kexi (--configure):
  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
  reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

This means it needs to be reinstalled. So, reinstall `kexi`, and it should fix that issue:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall kexi
```